# Combining two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a column `Full_Name` in `User` table which combines two columns of `First_Name and Last_Name`. This `Full_Name` column needs to update automatically by itself when `First_Name and Last_Name` fields are stored into database.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE User
ADD Full_Name AS(First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put an `UPDATE` at the bottom of your script every transaction like `INSERT` to update your `Full_Name` column.

```
    UPDATE [User] SET Full_Name = ISNULL(First_Name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Last_Name,'')
```